# Regarding JSOUP Working

Tags: android, jsoup

Does Jsoup updates data from a website everytime one use the app.?? i.e if ones JSOUP took data from a website, then will it take again the data when I again uses the application or just uses the data that was extracted before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup loads the data everytime you use the `parse()` or `get()`-Method. Those methods will return a `Document` containing all the code you work on.

So the content is not updated until you call `parse()` or `get()` again. You can select elements or make changes, but there wont be an update from the source.